# Returning from Observable call vs non-Observable using RxJava (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, rx-java

I have a function that takes a boolean input value, and depending on that, it needs to subscribe to an Observable in one case and immediately return in the other case.  Here is what it looks like:

```
fun getMap(needsReauth: Boolean): Map<String, Any>? {
    if (needsReauth) {
        AuthManager.reauthenticate().subscribe {
            return createMap()
        }
    } else {
        return createMap()
    }
}
```

The `reauthenticate()` method above returns an Observable, and it needs to be called and only return when complete.  Otherwise it can immediately return the value it gets from `createMap()`.

The two obvious issues are that I am getting the "return not allowed here" for the first return statement, and I'm getting an error because I'm not returning anything outside of the if-statement.

Is there a different way this can coded differently to work properly?  I tried some suggestions I found (i.e. naming the lambda, in-line function), but nothing seems to work, and I'm likely missing something obvious, assuming this is possible.

Edit: This method is a callback method in an interface that is triggered from a 3rd-party SDK, so I don't have flexibility around the actual method input or output.

Comment: one thing you can try is not returning, instead create a method and execute the block of code which you want to execute after getting map value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Would you mind expanding on this?  Unfortunately I do need to return from this method, as it's a callback that is required by a Vendor product whenever we need to re-auth, and the method is defined that way.

Comment: can you can tell me if you're using any one of architecture mvp or mvvm.

Comment: The app mostly uses MVVM

Comment: so I am guessing this logic would be inside the viewmodel, so either you would be needing this values in your view or viewmodel, if you need it in your view then update directly inside the view instead of returing, or if you need it inside your view model itself then make the parallel call to subsequent method with this map values as your argument.

Comment: one more suggestion can I can give you is make a interface and implement it whenever you need values, and when you can this method pass reference of that that interface, so that after it is executed you can call that interface method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AuthManager.reauthenticate()` is returning an `Observable` and you cannot refactor the caller of `getMap(...)` to accept an asynchronous result, you should be able to call `io.reactivex.Observable.blockingFirst()`, blocking the calling thread until the value is available:

```
fun getMap(needsReauth: Boolean): Map<String, Any>? {
    if (refreshContext) {
        AuthManager.reauthenticate().blockingFirst() // presumably validate the result?
    }

    return createMap()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  And for reference, if someone is using a version of Rx that does not have blockingFirst(), the syntax could also be:  toBlocking().first()

Comment: It's probably `blockingGet()` then.